# How to filter by a property 'today' in ng-repeat using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angular-filters

I have an ng-repeat on an array.
Each object has a property called `"checkdate"` which is just a `"New Date()"`.

I want the `ng-repeat` to only show objects created TODAY. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Here is what you can do to change a string to a date and compare `ng-repeat="obj in objects" ng-if="Date.parse(obj.checkdate) >= TODAY"` if this is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.list1 = [
  {name: "item1", checkdate: '2016-03-04T09:25:57.882Z'},
  {name: "item2", checkdate: '2016-03-05T09:25:57.882Z'},
  {name: "item3", checkdate: '2016-03-06T09:25:57.882Z'}];

var curDate = new Date();
var y = curDate.getFullYear();
var m = curDate.getMonth() + 1;
if (m < 10) {
  m = '0' + m;
}
var d = curDate.getDate();
if (d < 10) {
  d = '0' + d;
}
$scope.curDate = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
```

...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list1 | filter:{checkdate: curDate}">
  {{item.name}} - {{item.checkdate}}
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I should've been more thorough when describing this.

When a new entry is created, the checkdate field is populated by "new Date()". But it gets saved in the database as a string; like so:
2016-03-04T09:25:57.882Z

So this example will not work. Maybe I should create a function which strips the result after the date and compare only that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
ng-repeat="obj in objects"
```

and inside:

```
ng-show="obj.date === Date.now()"
```

And modify `Date.now()` according to the format of your objects date format.

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Or you can do the following:

`ng-show="checkDate(obj.date)"`

where

```
checkdate(date){
var todaysDate = new Date();
//call setHours to take the time out of the comparison
if(date.setHours(0,0,0,0) == todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0));
{
    return true
} else { return false}
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this http://codepen.io/utrolig/pen/YqwKpW
but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: filters wont work if you try to compare it to other value